# Appended html not globally selectable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, global

I'm trying hard to wrap my head around what techniques should be used when. I guess they just call that the "learning curve."

Why is it that the click function works when written like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Item = {
        list: function() {
            $.getJSON("output.php", function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                    $("ul#list").append(
                        '<li id="id' + val.id + '" class="itemContainer item' + val.category + '">' +
                        '<div class="item">' +
                            '<button name="plus" type="button" value="0" class="itemPlus">+</button>' +
                            '<button name="minus" type="button" value="0" class="itemMinus">-</button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</li>'
                    );
                });

                $("button").on("click", function() {
                    alert($(this).attr("name"));
                });
            });


        }
    }

    Item.list();


});
```

and doesn't work this way: (Notice I moved the $("button").on... outside the object)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var Item = {
        list: function() {
            $.getJSON("output.php", function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {

                    // HTML for Items. jQuery UI Templates?
                    // Select where list starts
                    $("ul#list").append(
                        '<li id="id' + val.id + '" class="itemContainer item' + val.category + '">' +
                        '<div class="item">' +
                            '<div class="catLabel"><div class="catColor catColor' + val.category + '"></div></div>' +
                            '<h2 class="itemTitle">' + val.title + '</h2>' +
                            '<img class="itemPic" src="img/noPic.gif" alt="No Picture Yet">' +
                            '<p class="itemDesc">' + val.desc + '</p>' +
                            '<hr/>' +
                            '<p class="itemDayPrice"><span class="itemDays">1</span> <a href="#">Day</a> Rental <sup>$</sup><span class="itemPrice">' + val.price + '</span></p>' +
                            '<button name="plus" type="button" value="0" class="itemPlus">+</button>' +
                            '<button name="minus" type="button" value="0" class="itemMinus">-</button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '</li>'
                    );
                });


            });


        }
    }

    Item.list();

    $("button").on("click", function() {
        alert($(this).attr("name"));
    });

});
```

I can't figure out if its the jQuery selector that needs to be inside, or the click function itself. Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated. Is there a better way I should be writing such code?

Any advice on js code writing styles would also be appreciated cause I have a feeling mine is horrible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on("click", "button", function() {
    alert($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

You have appended Elements Dynamically. They should be delegated.So, Use Above Thing To make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. This is a injected content need to delegate it.

```
$("ul#list").on("click", "button", function() {
     alert($(this).attr("name"));
});
```

Comment: It's these simple things that are making my hair gray. Thanks for the help Vins!